# Build failed -> task in 'ns3-lte' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)

Tags: python, ns-3

Build failed
-> task in 'ns3-lte' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/justice/Downloads/ns-allinone-3.35/./build.py", line 175, in 
sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
File "/Users/justice/Downloads/ns-allinone-3.35/./build.py", line 166, in main
build_ns3(config, build_examples, build_tests, args, build_options)
File "/Users/justice/Downloads/ns-allinone-3.35/./build.py", line 86, in build_ns3
run_command([sys.executable, "waf", "build"] + build_options)
File "/Users/justice/Downloads/ns-allinone-3.35/util.py", line 25, in run_command
raise CommandError("Command %r exited with code %i" % (argv, retval))
util.CommandError: Command ['/Users/justice/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3', 'waf', 'build'] exited with code 1

Comment: Can you please add some more details. Details such as what you are trying to accomplish, code samples and steps you have taken to try and solve the issue will greatly help us understand how to solve your issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I as trying to build the ns3

Comment: after downloading the NS3 I have to test it by building it ... on installing and building NS3 on MAC OS (12.3.1) Monterey.   link to the site I used `https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation`